# Prevent a query from duplicating

Tags: featured-post, post-duplication

Trying to show featured posts on home using catID,but it is being duplicated. Is there any way to prevent it from duplicating:

```
<?php
 query_posts("posts_per_page=1&cat=1");
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">continue reading</a></p>
<?php endwhile; ?> <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `wp_query` instead of `query_posts`

Comment: which part of templates is the best part for adding extra codes or editing as wishes content-page.php or content.php or index.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, you should never make use of [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) unless your intention is to break almost everything on your page :-)

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

To accomplish this, you should use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), and the [`post__not_in`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) parameter. You must first get an array of the all the post ID's on the page, and then use that to exclude those posts in your query

You can try something like this on your page

```
$post_ids = wp_pluck_list($wp_query->posts, 'ID'); 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'cat'            => 1,
    'post__not_in'   => $post_ids
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);

if ($q->have_posts()) {
    while($q->have_posts()) {
    $q->the_post();

       //Your loop

    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: if we want to retrieve posts based on specific cats such as "Featured", should we do like this: 'category_name' => Featured or ?

Comment: `category_name` should be the category slug, not the name. You can use that in place of `cat`

Comment: If you want to make use of the category name, you will need to use a `tax_query`, none of the category parameters accepts the category name